# 2 to the power of a matrix

Tags: matrices, exponential-function, exponentiation, matrix-exponential

I was watching 3b1b

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O85OWBJ2ayo

and I was wondering does there exist a definition for matrix exponentiation? Or is this concept of "matrix exponentiation" not well defined since we do not have a Taylor Series $\forall n \in\mathbb N$?

example: $2^\mathbf A$ or in general, $n^\mathbf A, \ n \in \mathbb N \land \mathbf A$ is a matrix.

I know this is probably nonsensical, but even if it isn't, it sounds interesting for how it could be used.

Comment: Did you mean "in general, $n^\mathbf A, \ n \in \mathbb Z \land \mathbf A$ is a matrix"? If so, you encounter problems when $n<0$.

Comment: @TonyK thanks not sure how i wrote that haha

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That makes sense, yes, as long as we are dealing with square matrices here. Define it as $\exp\bigl(\log(2)A\bigr)$, where$$\exp(M)=\operatorname{Id}+M+\frac1{2!}M^2+\frac1{3!}M^3+\cdots$$and note that this works for numbers: $\exp\bigl(\log(2)A\bigr)=\left(\exp\bigl(\log(2)\right)^A=2^A$.

Comment: It might be worth noting that $e^{A + B}$ is not necessarily equal to $e^A \times e^B$.

Comment: this is quite ingenious, thanks!

Comment: @badjohn Why is that?

Comment: @JohnD The better question is why should it?  When extending a definition to a larger structure, you cannot assume that all properties will be retained.  A common example of this mistake is assuming that $\sqrt (ab) = \sqrt a \sqrt b$ when you move from the real to the complex numbers.  In this case, it will be true if the matrices commute but might not be if they don't.  Try it with some simple non-commuting examples.